# Apache Poi: Converting from HSSF to SS?

Tags: apache-poi, poi-hssf

I've converted all of my old code in HSSF to SS except for the portion where I make the work book.

---

**Old Code:**
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));

---

**New Non-working Code:**
Workbook[] wb2 = new Workbook[] {new FileInputStream};

---

This is an example of conversion that the site gave:

NEW: Workbook[] wbs = new Workbook[] { new HSSFWorkbook(), new XSSFWorkbook() };
OLD: HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workbook is an interface, you can't instantiate it. Instead, what you want is [WorkbookFactory](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html). Pass that either a File or an InputStream, and it'll give you the appropriate Workbook instance

Your old code:

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));
```

Becomes:

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to import workbookfactory. It's not included in ss it seems

Comment: It is, just make sure you have the ooxml jar (and it's dependencies!). See the [components page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) for details